# Rails 4: Update checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a array as a field for a object and I am having problems to update it.

```
### members_controller.rb

 :special_role_attributes => [:member_id, :position_name => []]

 def update
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
 end

### _form.html.erb

<%= f.fields_for :special_role do |special| %>
 <%= special.collection_check_boxes :position_name, @special_positions, :position_name, :position_name %>
<% end %>
```

I can save it fine, but when I click to `update`, the checkboxes don't come checked.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your array `position_name`. Add this in your model

```
serialize :position_name, Array
```

To remove blank values add this

```
before_validation :cleanup_position_name

def cleanup_position_name
  position_name.reject!(&:blank?)
end
```

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do? I just did it and it's still not working.

Comment: Can you post your params here? There is noting to do more. We have one condition that when you have attribute as array, in params by default it will contain one `blank` value also. So, you need to ensure that this blank value should be removed before saving it into new record. You can do this with `before_validation` call back. Thanks

Comment: `params.require(:member).permit(:name, :special_role_attributes => [:member_id, :position_name => []]`

Comment: Show your params hash from rails rails console log while creating new record. Thanks

Comment: `position_name: ["Colunista Brasinhas", "Brasinhas", "Mentor BSCUE", ""]>`

Comment: thank you for your help. I did what you suggested and the method removes the `blank` space, however, when I put the serialize into the `special_role.rb`, it does not save the array anymore. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90352/discussion-between-vinicius-martinson-and-prakash-laxkar).